# Create calculated column min value in mysql 5.7

Tags: mysql-5.7

How to compute a column: calculation is to have 1 or 0
 If it is minimum value then 1 should be shown else 0

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understand, you can use either IF or CASE:

> ```
> create table tbl (f1 int, f2 int);
> ```

> ```
> insert into tbl values (1, 10);
> insert into tbl values (2, 12);
> insert into tbl values (3, 11);
> insert into tbl values (4, 16);
> insert into tbl values (5, 11);
> ```

Assuming 12 is the minimum value you are looking for:

> ```
> select f1, if(f2 < 12, 1, 0) as calc
> from   tbl;
> ```
>
> ```
> f1 | calc
> -: | ---:
>  1 |    1
>  2 |    0
>  3 |    1
>  4 |    0
>  5 |    1
> ```

> ```
> select f1, case when f2 < 12 then 1 else 0 end as calc
> from   tbl;
> ```
>
> ```
> f1 | calc
> -: | ---:
>  1 |    1
>  2 |    0
>  3 |    1
>  4 |    0
>  5 |    1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=ce5af37cb4eef14b5bc5045fc570e62e)*